# Flutter use web_socket_channel send binary frame stream auto close websocket

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

- Envionment:macos 14.3.1
- Stable flutter version: 3.19.2
- web_socket_channel: ^2.4.4

When i send a stream to wss server, The `onDown` method be invoked auto
Someone help me? There is my demo code:

record stream and send code:

```dart
Stream<Uint8List> recordStream = await _recorder.startStream(config);

    recordStream.listen(
      (data) {
        List<int> binaryData =
            _recorder.convertBytesToInt16(Uint8List.fromList(data));
        _channel.sink.addStream(Stream.fromIterable(binaryData));
      },
      onDone: () {
        print('Record done.');
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print('Record occur error: $error');
      },
```

wss channel connect code:

```dart
await _channel.ready;

    _channel.stream.listen(
      (message) {
        print(message);
      },
      onDone: () {
        print('Ws is done.');

        print(_channel.closeReason);
        if (_channel.closeCode != status.goingAway) {
          print('Ws is closed.');
        }
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print('Ws occur error: $error');
      },
    );
```

I had try to use `add()` method, issue is still there.

At first, I build a channel to wss: `_channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(wsUrl);`
Then send a text frame to it , it work perfect and i got listen callback: `_channel.sink.add(payload);`

but i send a stream next, websocket closed by no reason.
There is my logs:

```
flutter: {"header":{"appkey":"xxxxxxx","message_id":"7aefd166623b4b9f80d452a580a8f2f7","task_id":"b49441934424490795240605d7799505","namespace":"SpeechTranscriber","name":"StartTranscription"},"payload":{"format":"pcm","sample_rate":16000,"enable_punctuation_prediction":true}}

flutter: {"header":{"namespace":"SpeechTranscriber","name":"TranscriptionStarted","status":20000000,"message_id":"7d4ceda2dfbe4789b07f648637c803e8","task_id":"b49441934424490795240605d7799505","status_text":"Gateway:SUCCESS:Success."}}

flutter: Ws is done.

flutter: 

flutter: Ws is closed.
```